# Making a Div Dynamically using javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following HTML code for a DIv, i was wondering if there is way i can make same div programaticaly using Javascript / Jquery.

Or is there a way i can append div having class `"panel panel-default"` in div having ID `accordion` it as first element every time.
Thanks for help

Comment: id should be unique. Having a <div> with ID accordion every time defeats the purpose of an identifier.

Comment: "append as first element every time" <- do you mean prepend ?

Comment: You can make it. It is possible. But when do you create it?

Comment: `$('#accordion').prepend('<div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1"></div>')`?

Comment: @witherwind I want to create it on button click. If i click on ADD div should be inserted as first child of accordion

Comment: @ArunPJohny I tried it,but it just prepend it once, i want to prepend it everytime i click on ADD

Comment: can you recreate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zegb9/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Upadted jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zegb9/2/  Now when i click on add div which is hidden should be added as first child in accordion everytime

Comment: What do you mean? Awlad's answer fits the bill perfectly.

Comment: @witherwind It just prepend once, i need to add div every time on click.

Comment: I tried your fiddle, and yea, that's the case. What's #appendpanel btw?

Comment: Btw, use .clone(). That should do it.

Comment: @witherwind It is just an div which i want to add on click, and if i using clone click event are not working

Comment: What do you mean click event not working?

Comment: @witherwind Wheniclick on add a div is cloned, but click event don't work oncloned item. I added event listener, but after editing and clicking on add it shows edited div and notthe original div :(

Comment: You mean to say, when you cloned the div and edited it, the edited one will be cloned. Is that about right?

Comment: @witherwind Yes that is what is happening.But i want to show original div on click and not the edited div.  You can heck out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zegb9/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the markup to add some ids

```
<a id="clone">Add</a>
```

then

```
<div style="display:none" id="addme">...</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $cp = $('#addme');
    $('#clone').click(function(){
        $cp.children().clone().prependTo('#accordion')
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zegb9/)

Comment: Sir if i clone then click event won't work, i have edit and done option on every div.

Comment: Sir click event works now, but if i edit a div, and click add again it shows edited div, not the original one:(

Comment: @RS26 can you recreate the issue in the fiddle

Comment: Edited js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zegb9/5/.Click on add the it will add new div. Edit the new div andclick done. After that again click add, it shows edited divand not blank div :(

Comment: It is because of duplicate ids - $('#accordion').prepend($("#appendpanel").clone().removeAttr('id')); -  http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zegb9/6/

Comment: True that. I commented about it before. Seems it was ignored.

Comment: It is new question, i have list from created from which data is being fetched. Now this div should be added to list on done click

Comment: @RS26 it will be always better if you can have a demo(like jsfiddle) in the question so that we can experiment on it and don't have to spent time on recreating the issues

Comment: Sir it is an MVC application question and i don;t think JS fiddle will work on it. Should i create new question with complete details??

Comment: @RS26 that will be better... because I'll have to leave now & may not be able to work on it more.... if you post a different question others might be able to help you

Answer (score 2):

you can Use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [`.prependTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).

`prepend()` puts the prepending elem at first index

```
$('#accordion').prepend("<div> this is new div</div>");
```

Since you wanted to copy html each time in a click. you Should use unique id(#appendpanel is duplicating each time) and use `clone()`.For avoiding duplicate you can try this(use class name instead id)
[avoid copy id demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/86)

[**sample live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/83/)

Comment: Sir I tried it,but it just prepend it once, i want to prepend it everytime i click on ADD

Comment: It clones perfectly, but click event won't work like Edit and done on cloned div :( And even if click event works and editing is done, it will show edited div on next click and not the original div right??

Comment: although this is different question. here is the right fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zegb9/7/   do not forget to mark this answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using the createElement and assigning all of the attributes and adding them in the correct hierarchical order, there are a couple ways to do this.

1) enclose the elements as text and use `$.parseHTML( htmlString )` to return a DOM node.(this is jquery)

2) paste the html inside a `<script>` tag with it's type set to something like `type="html"`. The benefit of this is that if the script has an `id`, you can reference it via document.getElementById("idOfScriptTag"). The browser won't parse the contents of the script tag if it doesn't recognize its type, so you can just leave it on the page until you need it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to add some html code through javaScript/jquery at a paticular poisitionin the DOM.You can do it in the following way

```
$(".some_class_of_div" ).html(
                                '<div class="class1" style="position:absolute; width:25px !important; display:none;">\
                                        <img class="class2" src="http://xylz.com/static/img/black.png" style="width:30px;height:17px;padding-left: 10px;display:none;" title="try by click" >\
                                        <div class="class3" style="position:absolute; width:25px !important; padding-left: 10px;display:none;">\
                                            <img class="class4" src="http://xylz.com/static/img/border.png" style="width:20px;">\
                                            <div class="class5" style="position:absolute; width:25px !important;display:none;">\
                                                <img class="class6" src="http://xylz.com/static/img/settings.png" style="width:20px;">\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                </div>\
                                <form class="class7" method="get" style="display:none;" accept-charset="utf-8">\
                                    <input name="some_id" type="hidden" value="1">\
                                </form>');
```

Here I have used a class of div and added some html to it.The html can be anything you want.Instead of class you can also use id.hope that helps.